# script to determine a list of distribution patterns

Tags: python

I'm working on a card game design and am struggle to get some information.
I have 8 spaces and three "objects" R, B, and G.  I want to get a list of all possible distributions where there are 3 of two of the objects and 2 of the third.

Ex:

- r,b,r,g,r,b,g,b
- b,b,g,g,r,g,r,r
- etc.

Comment: Maybe provide both sample inputs and outputs, and some of the code you've tried already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are searching for all distinct subests of the string "RRRGGGBBB" which have a length of 8, including shuffles.

So this code probably gives you what you want-

```
import itertools
set(itertools.permutations("RGB" * 3, 8))
```

result-

```
{('G', 'B', 'R', 'G', 'B', 'R', 'G', 'B'),
 ('R', 'B', 'R', 'G', 'B', 'R', 'G', 'B'),
 ('R', 'G', 'B', 'G', 'B', 'R', 'G', 'B'),
 ('R', 'G', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'G', 'B'),
 ('R', 'G', 'B', 'R', 'G', 'B', 'G', 'B'),
 ('R', 'G', 'B', 'R', 'G', 'B', 'R', 'B'),
 ('R', 'G', 'B', 'R', 'G', 'B', 'R', 'G'),
 ('R', 'G', 'B', 'R', 'G', 'R', 'G', 'B'),
 ('R', 'G', 'R', 'G', 'B', 'R', 'G', 'B'), ....}
```

Comment: Very good,  I was about to post a solution that did this in two steps: first do all permutations of 'rgb', then use that to generate an 8-string and do the permutations, but this is simpler and, happily, gets the same answer.  1,680 sets.

Comment: I did the same, but I didn't notice the last parameter. In this case it wouldn't make that much difference, because selecting 8 elements in 9 is the same as selecting 9 and removing the last. Nevertheless, way cleaner and semantically accurate.

Comment: I was just about to post that 1680 is exactly how many sets OP is looking for as well from a mathematical perspective. 8! permutations of the string, but divide by (3! x 3! x 2!) since the order of the two triple letters and the double letter don't matter, and this is for the set with only 2 R's, only 2 G's, and only 2 B's, ... so 3 x 8! / (3! x 3! x 2!) = 1,680

Comment: I will check what I get from this but it sound like it will provide what I need.  I was going to brute force the answer, but new there had to be a simple tool.  Thanks!